# Intelij out of memory error with garbage collection issues

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm

In my project it throws out "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error and the program terminated. I tried to solve this with googling during our community and the following solutions while it still didn't work out.

1. Since I have to create a huge hashmap containing lots of arraylist/objects, I need to create these objects during the loop, so the ways to avoid making "new" objects may not work for my case.
2. Heap size: I already gave the heap big enough size with the commands "-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m".
3. Since I found this may be the issue that "more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and less than 2% of the heap is recovered", I add one more command "-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=50" which trigger the program to start collecting garbage when more than 50% of the heap is occupied. While the memory indicator of Intelij seems my program even not use this amount memory, the garbage collection should not start at all while it stills throw out the same error.
4. My code works well in Eclipse while it throws out this error in the latest version of Intelij, it should be some vm options configurations problems?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your project should run the same in any IDE or without an IDE. It is very strange if you managed to find a program which fails under one IDE but not another given the JVM runs as it's own process.  BTW 2GB isn't a lot of memory though that shouldn't matter.  I would trigger a heap dump and see where the memory is being used. I would also try giving the  program as much memory as you have up to say 32 GB and see how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I will try the way you mentioned.